# Is the following number not a Pisot-Vijayaraghavan number?

Tags: galois-theory, roots

Examples of Wikipedia “Pisot-Vijayaraghavan number” include the real roots of $x^3-x-1 = 0$ and $x^3-x^2-1 = 0$ as Pisot numbers.
Is the real root of $x^3-(x^2+x+1) = 0$ not a Pisot number? 
Because this equation has the following roots: $-0.4196433776070806 - 0.6062907292071994 i$, $-0.4196433776070806 + 
  0.6062907292071994 i$ and $1.8392867552141612$.
Their absolute values are $0.7373527057603277$, $0.7373527057603277$ and $1.8392867552141612$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The real root of $x^3 - (x^2 +x+1)=0$ is a Pisot-Vijayaraghavan number, since it's a real number greater than zero and all of its Galois conjugates have absolute value strictly less than $1$.